# Chrome Extension opens up all the specified links in contextMenus regardless of which option I am choosing. How can I avoid this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Good morning, I have been trying to fix this error myself but I cannot fully comprehend what it is going wrong yet. In summary:

- I have made a Chrome Extension that I would like to use kind of like a Bookmarks bar. The links within the extension will be supplied by myself. They all are URLs hosted online.
- In order for them to be easy to find, I have categorically organised them using the Chrome's contextMenus feature.
- Whenever I click one of the sections in the menu, instead of only opening the selected one it opens up ALL of them.

**manifest.JSON:**

```
{
"name": "My Chrome Extension",
"description": "Bookmarks in a Chrome Extension",
"version": "0.1",
"permissions": ["contextMenus","tabs"],
"background": {
"scripts": ["background.js"]
 },
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

**background.JS:**

```
// A generic onclick callback function.
function genericOnClick(info, tab) {
  console.log("item " + info.menuItemId + " was clicked");
  console.log("info: " + JSON.stringify(info));
  console.log("tab: " + JSON.stringify(tab));
}

// Create one test item for each context type.
var contexts = ["page", "selection", "link", "editable", "image", "video",
  "audio"
];
for (var i = 0; i < contexts.length; i++) {
  var context = contexts[i];
  var title = "Quick Access";
  var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": title,
    "contexts": [context],
    "onclick": genericOnClick
  });
  console.log("'" + context + "' item:" + id);
}

// Create a parent item and two children.
var parent1 = chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title": "Essentials"
});
var child1 = chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title": "Google",
  "parentId": parent1,
  "onclick": genericOnClick
});
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandlerGoogle);

function onClickHandlerGoogle(info, tab) {
  var urlgoogle = "https://www.google.com/";
  window.open(urlgoogle, '_blank');
};

var child2 = chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title": "CNN",
  "parentId": parent1,
  "onclick": genericOnClick
});
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandlerCNN);

function onClickHandlerCNN(info, tab) {
  var urlCNN = "https://www.cnn.com";
  window.open(urlCNN, '_blank');
};
```

Any ideas in regards of what you think it is wrong would be really appreciated!

**UPDATE** - background.JS now looks like this:**

```
// A generic onclick callback function.
function genericOnClick(info, tab) {
  console.log("item " + info.menuItemId + " was clicked");
  console.log("info: " + JSON.stringify(info));
  console.log("tab: " + JSON.stringify(tab));
}

// Create one test item for each context type.
var contexts = ["page","selection","link","editable","image","video",
            "audio"];
for (var i = 0; i < contexts.length; i++) {
  var context = contexts[i];
  var title = "Quick Access";
  var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts":[context],
                                   "onclick": genericOnClick});
  console.log("'" + context + "' item:" + id);
}

// Create a parent item and two children.
var parent1 = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Essentials"});
var child1 = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "id": "google",
    "title": "Google",
    "parentId": parent1,
    "onclick": genericOnClick
});
var child2 = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "id": "cnn",
    "title": "CNN",
    "parentId": parent1,
    "onclick": genericOnClick
});

function clickHandler(info, tab) {
    var url;
    switch(info.id) {
        case "google":
            url = "https://www.google.com";
            break;
        case "cnn":
            url = "https://www.cnn.com";
            break;
    }
    if (url) {
        window.open(url, "_blank");
    }
}
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(clickHandler);
```

These changes enable Chrome to run the extension with no errors, however, it will not open a link at all. I am currently still working through this and I really appreciate the time of the users that suggested changes.

If you notice something that looks strange, please do let me know!

Comment: `onClickHandlerGoogle` and `onClickHandlerCNN` are not bound to a specific item in the context menu, so they both run whenever you click on the context menu.

Comment: Also, switch to an [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have multiple listeners. They're all being run when you select from the menu, because there's nothing that attaches them to specific menu items.

Just define one listener, and it should check which menu item it's being run for and open the appropriate page. You'll need to add an `id` property to the menu items so you can dispatch on this.

```
var child1 = chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "id": "google",
  "title": "Google",
  "parentId": parent1,
  "onclick": genericOnClick
});
var child2 = chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "id": "cnn",
  "title": "CNN",
  "parentId": parent1,
  "onclick": genericOnClick
});

function clickHandler(info, tab) {
    var url;
    switch(info.menuItemId) {
    case "google":
        url = "https://www.google.com";
        break;
    case "cnn":
        url = "https://www.cnn.com";
        break;
  }
  if (url) {
      window.open(url, "_blank");
  }
}
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(clickHandler);
```

Comment: Hello Barmar, thank you very much for your response. Chrome is able to run the extension after I added your code. However, it will not open the link at all.

I have updated my question so it reflects the new code. I will keep trying to make it work. I really appreciate the time you spent writing that piece of code.

@wOxxOm - I was not able to switch it to an event page. As soon as I did, Google Chrome would not allow the extension to run.

Comment: Sorry, the name of the property in the `info` object is `menuItemId`.

Comment: Thank you so much Barmar! It is now working! I am very new to programming - And I believe you are a true asset to this site!